# beautifulsoup hidden data in search results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning beautifulsoup and tried to scrape results from websites like: Asos.com, Zara.com

From what I understand the results are hidden - what is the reason, and what's the best way to scrape search results from those websites?

Below my code at the moment, that doesn't generate anything.

Thank you!

```
        response = requests.get('https://www.zara.com/us/en/search?searchTerm={}')
        data = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser')
        post_listings = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'product _product '})
        final_postings = []
        for post in post_listings:
            post_title = post.find('a', {'class': 'name _item'}).text
            post_url = post.find('a').get('href')

            if post.find(span, {'class': 'main-price'}):
                post_price = post.find(span, {'class': 'main-price'}).text
```

Comment: check the data result first, if data has value, add headers in your request

Comment: I can't find the data I'm looking for in the returned html

Answer (score 0):

Running your code I have noticed that `post_listings = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'product _product '})` returns an empty list, so there is nothing to output.

Comment: So how can I scrape the results? any suggestion for code that would work?

Comment: Your code works fine, the only thing is that on the target page there are no elements with properties `'li', {'class': 'product _product '}`.